# Remove string portion from inconsistent string of comma-separated values

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2017 on Azure.

Given a field called `Categories` in a table called `dbo.sources`:

```
ID   Categories
1    ABC01, FFG02, ERERE, CC201
2    GDF01, ABC01, GREER, DS223
3    DSF12, GREER
4    ABC01
5    NULL
```

What is the syntax for a query that would remove `ABC01` from any record where it exists, but keep the other codes in the string?

**Results would be:**

```
ID   Categories
1    AFFG02, ERERE, CC201
2    GDF01, GREER, DS223
3    DSF12, GREER
4    NULL
5    NULL
```

Comment: If you fix the design, it would be far easier. Why are you storing delimited data? The *only* way you could do this would be to normalise your data, and then "de-normalise" it again/ Fix the design, the problem goes away.

Comment: Hi Larnu, I almost posted that this is not my design, that I unfortunately inherited it, and that while it's something we plan to optimize, it's not something we can do right now, and we need this short-term fix until we can.  I am quite sure there's a way to accomplish this with a query other than normalizing and de-normalizing.  It can be done in C#, and VB, so pretty sure it can be done in SQL.  Just need some guidance on the syntax.  I agree it would be WAY easier with the design fixed, and we will definitely do that, eventually.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 on Azure - I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: As I like to ask my boss when this type of project comes up. "I understand we can't schedule the time to fix this the right way currently because you need it right now. But let's put the real fix on the schedule so we don't end up here again. When can we schedule that?". You will be surprised with the answers you will receive.

Comment: Thanks, Sean, and you're preaching to the choir!  We're going to get it done.  The powers that be know that we are treading dangerous waters keeping our data in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Replace](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp) as follows:

```
update dbo.sources set
    category = replace(replace(category,'ABC01',''),', ','')
where category like '%ABC01%'
```

Comment: This works great until you have a category that is BABC01 or ABC012. But as a one time fix this may be sufficient.

Comment: Great point, Sean.  Fortunately we don't have any codes that would overlap like your example, and we'll hopefully have our schema fixed by the time we would!

Answer (score 2):

Normalising and then denormalising your data, you can do this:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Sources (ID int,
                          Categories varchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO dbo.Sources
VALUES (1,'ABC01,FFG02,ERERE,CC201'), --I **assume you don't really have the space)
       (2,'GDF01,ABC01,GREER,DS223'),
       (3,'DSF12,GREER'),
       (4,'ABC01'),
       (5,NULL);
GO

DECLARE @Source varchar(5) = 'ABC01'; --Value to remove

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT S.ID,
           STRING_AGG(NULLIF(SS.[value],@Source),',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY S.ID) AS Categories
    FROM dbo.Sources S
         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(S.Categories,',') SS
    GROUP BY S.ID)
UPDATE S
SET Categories = C.Categories
FROM dbo.Sources S
     JOIN CTE C ON S.ID = C.ID;
GO
SELECT ID,
       Categories
FROM dbo.Sources

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Sources;
```

Although this seems like a bit overkill, compared to the `REPLACE`, it shows why normalising it is a far better idea in the first place, and how simple it is to actually do so.